# Two number's doesn't equals but they have the same type and value

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have the problem that two identical values with the same type do not equals in Typescript/Javascript. 
*What I want to do:* I get data from a JSON and I want to join some data with other data of this JSON by id-attributes. The id's never match.

I've attached my files at the end. **The problem is in getStationNameById():
even if "id" is 2 and "station.id" is 2, they never equals.** They don't even equal with "== 2". I have absolutely no clue what the problem is. Due to my debug output both values are numbers.. but the result is ALWAYS false.

**my component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "../../services/data.service";

@Component({
    selector:    'alle-stationen-view',
    templateUrl: './src/html/alle-verbindungen-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './src/css/views-general.css', './src/css/alle-verbindungen-view.component.css']
})
export class AlleVerbindungenViewComponent implements OnInit {
    private connections: any[];
    private stations : any[];

    constructor(private dataService : DataService) {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
            data => this.dataHandler(data)
        );
    }

    private dataHandler(data) {
        let connections = data.connections || {};
        let stations    = data.stations    || {};
        this.stations = stations;
        connections.forEach(function(connection) {

            // TO DO: DOESNT WORK!
            connection.fromStation = this.getStationNameById(connection.fromStationId);
            connection.toStation   = this.getStationNameById(connection.toStationId);
        }, this);
        this.connections = connections;
    }

    private getStationNameById(id : number) {
        console.debug("---");
        this.stations.forEach(function(station) {
            // both have Constructor "Number"
            console.debug("id.type="+id.constructor+", station.id.type="+station.id.constructor);
            console.debug("id="+id+", station.id="+station.id);
            console.debug("station.id==id : "+station.id == id)+""; // ALWAYS FALSE
            console.debug("station.id===id: "+station.id === id+""); // ALWAYS FALSE
            console.debug("id == 2:" +id==2); // ALWAYS FALSE
            console.debug("station.id == 2:" +station.id==2); // ALWAYS FALSE
            if (station.id === id) {
                return station.name;
            }
        });
        return "";
    }
}
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "data": {
    "stations": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hamburg Mitte"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hamburg Ost"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Hamburg Hauptbahnhof"
      }
    ],
    "connections": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "fromStationId": 1,
        "toStationId": 2,
        "duration": 7
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "fromStationId": 2,
        "toStationId": 1,
        "duration": 7
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "fromStationId": 1,
        "toStationId": 3,
        "duration": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "fromStationId": 3,
        "toStationId": 1,
        "duration": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "fromStationId": 2,
        "toStationId": 3,
        "duration": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "fromStationId": 2,
        "toStationId": 2,
        "duration": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**console output**

```
id.type=function Number() { [native code] }, station.id.type=function Number() { [native code] }
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:39 id=1, station.id=1
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:40 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:41 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:42 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:43 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:38 id.type=function Number() { [native code] }, station.id.type=function Number() { [native code] }
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:39 id=1, station.id=2
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:40 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:41 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:42 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:43 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:38 id.type=function Number() { [native code] }, station.id.type=function Number() { [native code] }
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:39 id=1, station.id=3
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:40 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:41 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:42 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:43 false
alle-verbindungen-view.component.ts:35 ---
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct ansewr, so I will place it here only as a comment. From how I'm interpreting your code, I think the problem is that you are actually comparing an integer value to what's really a *function*, thus explaining why the equality check always fails. Note in your log the "id.type" is a function prototype, but in the other log "id" is a value...

Comment: @DavidW I have pasted the reason why phip1611 getting false.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it in wrong way.

In your code you are using `console.debug("id == 2:" +id==2);` which will compare "id==2" == 2 means you are comparing string with 2.

For example try this `console.debug("id == 2:" +2==2);` You will get false, because you are actually comparing `"id == 2:2" == 2` which will always give you false.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

**EDIT :**
In this statement we are using two operator `+` and `==` and `+` have higher precedence then `==`. So firstly `+` get execute then `==` get execute.

Comment: Okay, but even if my additional debug output is not right, why is ***if (station.id === id) {}*** never true?

Comment: OK, then can you please try with `typeof station.id === typeof id` what it returns.

Comment: It returns true for all id-values

Comment: How about forcing evaluation to the test expression via parenthesis, eg 'console.debug("id == 2:" + (id==2));

Comment: Yes we can do that.

Comment: (id==2) is true (if id is 2) and (station.id==2) is also true (if station.id is 2). But why is id == station.id always false even if both have the value 2?

Comment: It can't be possible that you have same type and same value, still you are getting error. Please check where you are doing mistake in verifying.

Comment: @phip1611 Could you update your post with the results from having forced the evaluation with the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Due to I had wrongly debug output I searched at a wrong place for the bug. Now after I used parenthesis I received true results. I thought that the return in the forEach-function affected the whole method and not just this block. Therefore the method returned "" all the time. This works now:

```
private getStationNameById(id : number) {
    let stationName : string = "";
    this.stations.forEach(function(station) {
        if ((station.id) === id) {
            stationName = station.name;
        }

    });
    return stationName;
}
```